# Use of setting ValidateRequest to false in ASP

Tags: asp.net

What is the use of setting ValidateRequest to False in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

It is used to prevent [XSS attacks.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)  If you set it to False, request validation for XSS attacks will not happen. Note that it is not a fool-proof method to prevent XSS

Answer (score 0):

`ValidateRequest` will prevent any Request that has square brackets (HTML tag brackets) from getting to the server. This is to prevent (or try to help in preventing) inserting malicious HTML tags (specifically, `<script>`) into the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to prevent XSS attacks and as such defaults to true. However this means that when you want to pass in certain characters like `<script` in one of your textboxes you error out as it's not permitted.

Setting it to false however opens the door for attacks so only set it as such after some consideration.

Microsoft also released the [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en) which you could use instead.

Grz, Kris.